# Javascript pattern setup difference

Tags: javascript, namespaces, design-patterns

I am working on a small one-page scrolling site with the use of jQuery. Being new to javascript, I've come across many different ways other developers organize their code. With a simple site with small javascript interaction, I'm wondering what the difference is between the following snippets of code that I've seen on other sites.

First

```
var NS = NS || NS
NS = {
    init: function() {},
    buildNav: function() {},
    scrollToSection: function() {}
}

$( document ).ready( NS.init() );
```

Second

```
var NS = NS || NS;
NS = new (function() {
    var name = 'Basic';
    var self = this;
    self.getName = function() { return name; };
});
NS.Home = new (function() {
    // variables..are these private or public
    var self = this;
    self.init = function() {
      // initiate
    }

    self.scrollToSection = function() {
      // scroll section
    }

    // public or private method?
    function buildNav() {
    }
});

$(document).ready(function() { NS.Home.init(); });
```

Third

```
var NS = NS || NS;

NS.Home = new function() {
  var foo = $('#htmlelement');

  this.scrollToSection() {
    // scroll section
  };
  this.init = function() {
    buildNav();
  };

  function buildNav() { }
}
$( document ).ready( NS.Home.init() );
```

Forth

```
(function($){
    $.fn.homepage = function() { 
        function buildNav() { }
        function init () { } 
    };
    $.fn.otherpage = function() {
        function doSomething() { }
        function init () { }
     }
})(jQuery);

$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#homepage-element').homepage();
}
```

Comment: You do one mistake everytime: `$( document ).ready( NS.Home.init() );` This calls the function immediately - remove the `()` to pass it to the ready function instead so it can be called when the DOM is actually ready.

Comment: `var NS = NS || NS` is an obsolete line.

Comment: ThiefMaster - so it should be `$( document ).ready( NS.Home.init );`

Comment: What exactly is the `var NS = NS || NS` doing? I've seen it being used on other sites. Is it just making sure that NS exists? I'm new to JS / jQuery so any help / pointing in the right direction would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `var NS = NS || NS;`
   This line initialises NS to a default value if the passed value is null or undefined. All the three create a singleton object of `NS` - which acts like a namespace.
2. First, Second and Third explain different styles of object oriented programming practices.
3. In First, the NS object is created via object literal notation and therefore all its functions are public, and variable that you will be creating for NS will also be public.
4. Second and Third are quite similar, except Second is more messy and Third is more crisp.
   Second and Third both declare some exposed methods on the NS object (created via anonymous constructor) and some private functions.
5. Second and Third declare an property dynamically by the use of anonymous constructor function.

You should read a few articles about object oriented javascript and design patterns.
Start with [this one](http://addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/)

Comment: Thank you very much. Will spend the next couple of days reading up on this stuff!

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the content presented [here](http://www.elijahmanor.com/2011/04/mix11-video-good-javascript-habits-for.html) by Elijah Manor.  Some really good presentations and content on javascript best practices.